# the following sites are plagerising questions from stack exchange. How do I get these URL's to the legal department for them to investigate further

Tags: support, plagiarism, legal

I had a question on stack overflow that was deleted some time back but should be deleted for good for personal reasons (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15916165/psexec-wont-forward-stdout-err-in).  Searching the question online resulted in other websites that are using my question and my name without my consent or permission.
They are the following:

http://nerdanswer.com/answer.php?q=128935

http://witlogs.com/Questions/163286/is-there-a-way-to-get-PSEXEC-to-output-the-results-of-python

https://www.ngxo.com/search/psexec/9

This is not only a violation of the TOS, but a violation of my privacy since they use my name with out agreement from me.

How do I deliver these sites to the legal department for review?

Comment: I have voted to close this, but it doesn't mean that your request is not valid. In fact, you are welcomed to do so. Please check the other question for the procedure. Thanks.

Comment: BTW I've retracted my vote to close as duplicate.  That other question deals specifically with sites that are not attributing and linking back to the original.  This question appears to be protesting ALL copies.  NGXO at least appears to be making an effort to comply with the attribution and license requirements on [its copy](https://www.ngxo.com/thread/15916165)

Comment: Your old password is still in the edit history on Server Fault too.

Answer (score 1):

> a violation of my privacy since they use my name without agreement from me.

That's not actually true.  By submitting a question to SO, you licensed it under CC BY-SA (check the bottom of the page).

You're free to grant additional licenses under other terms, but making it available under that license it a condition of contributing questions, answers, comments, edits... basically anything.

And deleting the question here does not revoke the license.

You can contact the SE team to request that your password be scrubbed from old revisions of the question (which btw can still be seen by privileged users), but that still doesn't revoke the license.  Nor do people willing to do improper things using your credentials care one whit about the legality of publishing copies.

## Change the password already!

Comment: Already done; yet another boneheaded copy paste error. but I would assume that other sites would be discouraged from copying material posted on this site.

Comment: @RustyWeber: Well, [your assumption is wrong](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/)